# Basic Lex file for Hoc1 in book "Unix Programming Environment"

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

In the book "Unix Programming Environment" the book relies on writing its own lexer for all but one of the examples in the chapter on writing "hoc".

I would really like to see the use of lex for the first example hoc1.  When I try to write my own using lex, the program doesn't output a response until I come up with a syntax error.

The code could be seen at the
[Unix Programming Environment](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/upe/) website — now via the Wayback Machine: [The UNIX Programming Environment](https://web.archive.org/web/20140815003051/http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/upe/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

#### hoc1lex.l

```
$ cat hoc1lex.l
%{
extern int lineno;
#define YYSTYPE double
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

[ \t]
\n                                   { lineno++; return('\n'); }
[0-9]*\.[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?    { yylval = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)? { yylval = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
.                                    { return *yytext; }

%%
```

#### Context diff for hoc.y to hoc1.y

```
$ diff -u hoc.y hoc1.y
--- hoc.y   1995-06-12 16:30:21.000000000 -0700
+++ hoc1.y  2011-09-18 18:59:02.000000000 -0700
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 %{
+#include <stdio.h>
 #define    YYSTYPE double  /* data type of yacc stack */
 %}
 %token NUMBER
@@ -19,7 +20,6 @@
 %%
    /* end of grammar */
 
-#include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 char   *progname;  /* for error messages */
 int    lineno = 1;
@@ -31,6 +31,7 @@
    yyparse();
 }
 
+#if 0
 yylex()        /* hoc1 */
 {
    int c;
@@ -48,6 +49,7 @@
        lineno++;
    return c;
 }
+#endif /* 0 */
 
 yyerror(s) /* called for yacc syntax error */
    char *s;
```

#### hoc1.mk makefile

```
$ cat hoc1.mk
YFLAGS = -d

hoc1:   hoc1.o hoc1lex.o
    cc hoc1.o hoc1lex.o -o hoc1 -lfl

hoc1lex.o:  y.tab.h
```

#### Build and test

```
$ make -f hoc1.mk
yacc -d hoc1.y 
mv -f y.tab.c hoc1.c
cc    -c -o hoc1.o hoc1.c
lex  -t hoc1lex.l > hoc1lex.c
cc    -c -o hoc1lex.o hoc1lex.c
cc hoc1.o hoc1lex.o -o hoc1 -lfl
rm hoc1lex.c hoc1.c
$ ./hoc1
1.2 + 2.3
    3.5
2.3/1.2
    1.9166667
$
```

Comment: Thanks - after a couple of trivial modifications of your code it worked on my system.  I was missing the last line in the lex file referring to "." - in my original attempts.  Could that have prevented the program from working?

Comment: Succinctly - yes.  In particular, it would mean that the scanner did not recognize the operators ('+', '-', etc) at all, so the grammar would never see them.